# Will SecureString give me any advantage when it comes to MSIL decompilation?

Tags: c#, .net, securestring

Is it in any way better to do this

```
char[] sec = { 'a', 'b', 'c'};

SecureString s = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in sec) {
    s.AppendChar(c);
}

IntPtr pointerName = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(s);
String secret = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(pointerName);
```

than this

```
String secret = "abc";
```

or this

```
char[] sec = { 'a', 'b', 'c'};
String secret = new Secret(sec);
```

if I want to protect "abc" from beeing detected in decompiled MSIL code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SecureString will protect your string once in memory, the string compiled into your MSIL will still be there in plain. If you need to hide sensitify information conside something like an encrypted app.config as described here: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

HTH
Dominik

Answer (score 3):

No. [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) exists to prevent sensitive text (such as passwords) from being held in memory.